# New Tween not working correctly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

A bit confused as to where Im going wrong here

I have a dynamic text field, called myText.
Im running the below code:

```
package  {
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.Elastic;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;


public class video extends MovieClip {


    public function video() {


        var fmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

        var letterTween:Tween = new Tween(fmt, "letterSpacing", Elastic.easeInOut, 6, 15, 2, true);

        myText.setTextFormat(fmt);



    }
}
```

}

I know its targeting the text as the text letter spacing is set to 6 when running, but nothing happens, I dont get me nice tween to 15 letter spaces(ing)

where am I going wrong?

thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you don't see any updates is because when `TextFormat` properties change, you have to reapply the `TextFormat`. All you need to do is listen for updates from the `Tween` and apply it there.

My example was tested on the timeline in CS5, go ahead and amend your class accordingly.

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.Elastic;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

var fmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
var letterTween:Tween = new Tween(fmt, "letterSpacing", Elastic.easeInOut, 6, 15, 2, true);
letterTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_CHANGE, onMotionChanged);
myText.setTextFormat(fmt);

function onMotionChanged(event:TweenEvent):void{
    myText.setTextFormat(fmt);
}
```